# Исключение в Django , json

Tags: python, json, django

Всем привет!
Создал веб-сайт которая показывает погоду, данные появляются из json файла.Нужно чтобы если писать в строку неправильное название города, то появлялось окно типа "Неправильное название города". Пожалуйста, скажите, как можно так сделать если данные берутся из json  файла

views:

```
    def index(request):
    appid = '04df3bd974e178dfde66e1f7428c5a7b'
    url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=metric&appid=' + appid

    d = City.objects.all()
    d.delete()

    if(request.method == 'POST'):
            form = CityForm(request.POST)
            form.save()
            
    form = CityForm()


    cities = City.objects.all()

    all_cities = []

    for city in cities:
        res = requests.get(url.format(city.name)).json()
        city_info = {
            'city': city.name,
            'temp': res["main"]["temp"],
            'icon': res["weather"][0]["icon"],
            'speed': res["wind"]["speed"],
            'humidity': res["main"]["humidity"],
        }
        all_cities.append(city_info)

    context = {'all_info': all_cities, 'form':form}

    return render(request, 'weather/index.html', context)
```

Название отправляется через эту строку index.html

````
    <h1>Погода в вашем городе</h1>
          <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="city">Город</label>
            {{ form.name }}
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Узнать" class="mt-2 btn btn-danger">
          </form>```
````

Comment: будет проще, если ты покажешь код, который уже есть, что бы было от чего отталкиваться

Comment: Добавил код, если что то не хватает добавлю)

Comment: `res = requests.get(url.format(city.name)).json()` передай неверный город в эту строку и посмотри, что получишь в res. В дальнейшем когда заносишь данные в `city_info` проверяй этот ответ и заполняй соответствующе

Comment: туда передаются правильные и неправильные, потом имя города заносится в ссылку и срабатывает json файл. Но если туда попадет неправильно имя , то появляется ошибка "KeyError at /" , нужно чтобы при неправильном написании появилась ошибка " типа неправильное название".

Comment: если появляется keyError то скорее всего делай проверку, `if city.get("name")`, если `True` значит есть данные, иначе выдавай сообщение об ошибке

Comment: Нужно написать до цикла , да? Возможно задаю , тупые вопросы, просто недавно начал учить(

Comment: нет, тут я натупил. я не правильно написал код, дай то, что получаешь в res при неправильном городе

Comment: Просто не неправильном городе появляется ошибка "KeyError at /
'main'
"

Comment: добавил ответ, посмотри

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for city in cities:
        res = requests.get(url.format(city.name)).json()
        if res.get("main"):
            city_info = {
                'city': city.name,
                'temp': res["main"]["temp"],
                'icon': res["weather"][0]["icon"],
                'speed': res["wind"]["speed"],
                'humidity': res["main"]["humidity"],
                'error': False,
            }
        else:
            city_info = {
                'city': city.name,
                'error': True,
            }
        all_cities.append(city_info)
```

Вариант 2:
Если нужна проверка только по одному городу, который ввел пользователь, то цикл не нужен

```
if(request.method == 'POST'):
        form = CityForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            res = requests.get(url.format(form.cleaned_data("city")).json()
            if res.get("main"):
                city_info = {
                    'city': city.name,
                    'temp': res["main"]["temp"],
                    'icon': res["weather"][0]["icon"],
                    'speed': res["wind"]["speed"],
                    'humidity': res["main"]["humidity"],
                } 
            else:
               return HttpResponseRedirect("<URL_НА_КОТОРЫЙ_НАДО_ПЕРЕНАПРАВИТЬ>")
```

Comment: Cпасибо тебе большое, а можно сделать так, чтобы в неправильном названии тебя отправляли на другую страницу, которую я создал , которая показывает ошибку

Comment: судя по коду у тебя идет обработка сразу многих городов. Часть может быть верными, часть нет, поэтому не понятно когда именно ты хочешь перенаправлять на другую страницу

Comment: Перенаправлять нужно будет когда имя написано неправильно, а  с помощью твоего когда, просто появляется неправильно название на месте, где появлялась погода

Comment: если у тебя здесь должна идти проверка только по одному городу(который ввел пользователь), тогда скорее всего цикл не нужен, сейчас подправлю код